# How to search through date_format field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have changed the date format of field, however its not finding the record on new date pattern.

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%d-%m-%Y") AS sale_date 
FROM sales 
WHERE sale_date = '31-12-2012';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%d-%m-%Y") AS sale_date 
FROM sales 
WHERE sale_date = STR_TO_DATE('31-12-2012' , "%d-%m-%Y") ;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%d-%m-%Y") AS sale_date 
FROM sales 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%d-%m-%Y") = '31-12-2012';
```

Comment: Indeed, this will work, but applying the DATE_FORMAT function in the where clause to the sale_date column would cause it to ignore any index on column sale_date... I'm going to assume if they're looking up by sale_date they've got it indexed.

Comment: Check my other query it will apply the indexon sale date column

Comment: Yes, the second query will not break the index.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a `timestamp` or `date` format for your column `sale_date`, you must specify the date like  YYYY-MM-DD:

```
    WHERE sale_date = '2012-12-31';
```

Comment: @TPSstar:  Mysql *always* uses [ISO8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for writing dates in expressions.

Comment: @Ray Yes i know about that but i want to search on my defined format, which is "%d-%m-%Y"

Comment: @TPSstar Sorry, your question didn't indication you were unable to change the string provided.  Saharsh's second query in his answer above should do the trick.